# How to handle advanced search, search, and in-doc search?

Tags: search

We have a very large internal website that has a landing page.  The page has some content on it and some subpages but 80-90% of the focus is to let people search for internal documents.

So we have a search input bar with a search button right under the main menu (which is just just a floating bar).  Right after the search button is checkbox+"in-doc search".  So if they check that they get the same search results that also scan through document body.

On the main menu above the search one of the top layer links is simply Advanced Search.  Well they want me to incorporate this into the search bar.  However the Advanced Search just goes to another page where you do your advanced search.  So if it were another button it might confuse people thinking what they type into the search box would be part of the Advanced Search.

So wondering what the best way to have these 3 elements in one bar so that the user isn't confused.

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot or a draft sketch?

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't make "Advanced Search" a button, I'd rather make it a link. So users wouldn't mistake it for a call-to-action. See the following picture.

[image: search box on setlist.fm]

Apart from that: is the checkbox really necessary? Wouldn't tweaking the sorting of the search results by relevancy bring better results (quite literally)? E.g. if someone searches "Blue Widgets" then documents with "Blue Widgets" in the title would have preference over the documents where it only appears in the title.

Comment: We are using a big vendor for backend.  If I could I would tweak things like that but as is things are pretty set in stone.  (they charge us 50-100k for the smallest tweaks)

Comment: Well then please provide a screenshot or a draft sketch as @Stevy suggested and explain what you're able to change and what's "set in stone".